# Selenium opens new tab after SendKeys

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I'm trying to test my web app with selenium. For testing i'm using Selenium 3.5.2, chromeWebDriver 2.33 and chrome version 62.

The problem is that after i create action and call sendKeys, chrome opens help tab. I tried on differents web pages, even on youtube. Here's code:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.Id("search_field"));
actions.sendKeys(element, "A").build().perform();
```

After `perform()` chrome opens a new help tab.

Thank you for answers!

Comment: What happens with element.sendKeys("A") method? Does the help tab open up?

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/30150/chrome-62-sendkeys-seems-to-be-causing-chrome-settings-help-to-open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same new tab opening issue as soon as chrome browser got updated from Version 61.0.xxx to Version 62.0.3202.62 (Official Build) (64-bit) on 10/20/2017

By then my configs were;
Mac OS, Selenium 3.4.0, chromedriver 2.30

Today i updated the chrome driver to chromedriver 2.33 staying in Selenium 3.4.0 and it resolved the problem. Also no harm updating to Selenium 3.5.3

Comment: For protractor users, make sure the chromedriver in `node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium` has the 2.33 binary

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with:

- Chrome Browser Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Selenium 3.5.3
- chromedriver 2.33

  ```
      String chromeDriver = "pathTo/chromedriver";
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriver);
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/");
      WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gs_lc0']"));
      Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
      actions.sendKeys(element, "A").build().perform();
  ```

and it works. I think you should update Selenium from 3.5.2 to (at least) 3.5.3

Answer (score 0):

updating chrome driver to 2.33 worked for me.